# SQL displaying rows with duplicate values in 3 Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Hi I have a following table say price

```
CostID   ItemID  Level  EffectiveFrom EffectiveTo            
6274751  12345   1       12/02/2013   NULL
6274751  12345   1       13/02/2013   NULL
6274751  12345   2       12/02/2013   NULL
6254784  12345   1       12/02/2013   NULL
6254784  12345   1       13/02/2013   NULL
6244784  12345   9       12/02/2013   NULL
```

I would like to be able to write a query to find the duplicate rows by comparing 3 columns 'CostID' 'ItemID' and 'Level' and display the ones that are duplicates only

Expected Output Part 1

```
CostID   ItemID  Level  EffectiveFrom EffectiveTo            
6274751  12345   1       12/02/2013   NULL
6274751  12345   1       13/02/2013   NULL
6254784  12345   1       12/02/2013   NULL
6254784  12345   1       13/02/2013   NULL
```

Once I get the result above and I would like to update the EffectiveTo table from the last duplicate row

Expected Output for Part 2

```
CostID   ItemID  Level  EffectiveFrom EffectiveTo            
6274751  12345   1       12/02/2013   13/02/2013
6274751  12345   1       13/02/2013   NULL
6254784  12345   1       12/02/2013   13/02/2013
6254784  12345   1       13/02/2013   NULL
```

I tried this:

```
{
SELECT *
FROM price
WHERE ItemID IN
    (     SELECT ItemID
          FROM price
          GROUP BY ItemId          HAVING COUNT(distinct level) > 1
    )
ORDER BY CostID }
```

for the first part of the query but couldn't get the results I want, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What sql are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2005, Thanks for formatting it for me

Comment: There is so many you wanted determine. Please be specific. Please provide your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the duplicate rows:

```
select distinct p.*
from price p
join price q
    on p.CostID = q.CostID
    and p.ItemID = q.ItemID
    and p.Level = q.Level
    and p.EffectiveFrom != q.EffectiveFrom
```

The condition `p.EffectiveFrom != q.EffectiveFrom` is important because it stops all rows joining to themselves. Normally, you would simply compare an id column for inequality, but your table doesn't seem to have one.

---

To update the older row with a suitable end date:

```
update p set
p.EffectiveTo = dateadd(day, -1, q.EffectiveFrom)
from price p
join price q
    on p.CostID = q.CostID
    and p.ItemID = q.ItemID
    and p.Level = q.Level
    and p.EffectiveFrom < q.EffectiveFrom
```

The only real difference with this query is changed the inequality to a less-than, thus selecting for update only those rows that are the earlier ones.

Note that I've subtracted 1 day from the later date so there's no overlap.

Comment: Using this query, I get way too many results though, if I have 41,000 records on my Table, after running the query I get 100,000 records. All I wanted to see was something around 1,000 duplicate records so I could manually perform Part 2.  Like in my example I had 6 records and after running query I would like to see the 4 that are duplicates.  Thanks

Comment: Do you have several (more than 2) rows with the same key data?

Comment: When I ran the second query it says the Table 'price' is ambiguous

Comment: It would see you have many records with the sand values, so I have added the `distinct` keyword to solve that: the first query should be OK now. As for the update, I have corrected that too, although it is much more complicated with multiple shared records. It will work (not error) but you coukd have several rows with the same date

Comment: Sorry, I used price instead on update p set so I was getting that error, however once I fixed that I get a new error that effectiveTo cannot be updated, however I can manually copy the date and time and paste it and it works fine.

Comment: 12/05/2010 12:00:00 AM is my actual date and time format would this have made any difference ?

Comment: No - the main thing is that rows don't join to themselves

Answer (score 0):

This one is a bit long...but you can make some improvements.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CostID, ItemID, Level ORDER BY CostID, EffectiveFrom) AS RNUM,
        CostID,
        ItemID,
        Level,
        EffectiveFrom,
        EffectiveTo
    FROM @Price
),
cteDup AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CostID, ItemID, Level FROM cte WHERE RNUM > 1
)
SELECT tt.* FROM @Price tt
INNER JOIN cteDup cc ON tt.CostID = cc.CostID AND tt.ItemID = cc.ItemID AND tt.Level = cc.Level
```

**UPDATE:** This will make a direct update, not sure if this is what you want tho.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CostID, ItemID, Level ORDER BY CostID, EffectiveFrom) AS RNUM,
        CostID,
        ItemID,
        Level,
        EffectiveFrom,
        EffectiveTo
    FROM @Price
)
UPDATE c1 SET 
     EffectiveTo = c2.EffectiveFrom
FROM cte c1
INNER JOIN cte c2 ON c1.CostID = c2.CostID  AND c1.ItemID = c2.ItemID AND c1.Level = c2.Level AND c1.RNUM + 1 = c2.RNUM
```

Comment: This gives me the result perfectly, but cannot update once the result is displayed though.  Is there an update query to achieve Part 2 without having to do Part 1 ?